# Spreadsheet not found in the workbook, even if that spreadsheet exists

Tags: excel, vba

I have this small piece of code:

```
NombreLibro = Application.GetOpenFilename()
Set Libro = Workbooks.Open(NombreLibro, , False)

If Val(Application.Version) > 15 Then  'I tried this but it doesn't solve the problem
    Libro.AutoSaveOn = False
End If

With Libro
    For i = 1 To .Worksheets.Count
        If .Worksheets(i).CodeName = "Sheet1" Then 'HERE I HAVE THE PROBLEM
            (doing something)
            
        End If
    Next i
End With
```

Sometimes the "if" is false even if the workbook actually has the "Sheet1".
But if I run this again, adding a stop in the code to check what is going on, then the piece of code works as expected.

I am downloading the workbooks from a company website and run the code right away.
I have OneDrive in my computer. So I am wondering if OneDrive is busy uploading the file and then Excel doesn't access it correctly?

What do you suggest I could try?

EDIT:

Following VBasic2008 suggestion (see his/her answer) I changed a little the code, but it kept failing. I then added a debug MsgBox:

```
For Each ws In Libro.Worksheets
    MsgBox "CodeName: " & ws.CodeName & vbLf _
        & "Name: " & ws.Name & vbLf & "Libro: " & Libro.Name  'I added this

    If ws.CodeName = wsCodeName Then
        wasFound = True
        Exit For ' The worksheet is found, no need to loop anymore.
    End If
Next ws
```

Result (shown in the MsgBox):

CodeName:                     'blank!!!

Name: SheetName               'correct

Libro: LibroName              'correct

Is there a bug in Excel related to CodeNames?

EDIT2: (WORKAROUND)

I download the files from a company website, the data on the website is on a table and then a converter downloads it into Excel format.

I think the downloaded file is not quite Excel format and the CodeName is not filled. When Excel opens it and then the VBA editor is opened, Excel fills out the CodeName with a standard name.

In my case, as the fresh downloaded files have only one sheet, I can use this workaround:

```
For Each ws In Libro.Worksheets
    If ws.CodeName = wsCodeName Or ws.CodeName = "" Then
        wasFound = True
        Exit For 
    End If
Next ws
```

This will work the first time the file is processed `ws.CodeName = ""` and the next times `ws.CodeName = wsCodename`

Comment: `codename` is a property of the sheet, which you need to set. If you're looking for a sheet named "sheet1" then you need to iterate through the sheets until you get a match from the range.

Comment: @ spikey_richie That part is correct, the codename is Sheet1, the name is different. If that were the case, the code wouldn't work after a few minutes, without changing anything.

Answer (score 1):

### Using Worksheet CodeName

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub testCodeName()

    Const wsCodeName As String = "Sheet1"
    
    ' Choose file (workbook, spreadsheet).
    Dim NombreLibro As Variant
    NombreLibro = Application.GetOpenFilename()
    
    ' Validate workbook.
    If NombreLibro = False Then
        MsgBox "You canceled.", vbExclamation, "Canceled"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Open and create a reference to the workbook.
    Dim Libro As Workbook: Set Libro = Workbooks.Open(NombreLibro, , False)
    
    ' Attempt to find the worksheet.
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim wasFound As Boolean
    For Each ws In Libro.Worksheets
        If ws.CodeName = wsCodeName Then
            wasFound = True
            Exit For ' The worksheet is found, no need to loop anymore.
        End If
    Next ws

    ' Validate worksheet.
    If Not wasFound Then
        MsgBox "Worksheet not found.", vbExclamation, "Not Found"
        Exit Sub
    End With
    
    ' Continue with the code
    With ws
        ' e.g. see if it's true.
        MsgBox "Worksheet found:" & vbLf _
            & "Name: " & .Name _
            & vbLf & "CodeName: " & .CodeName, vbInformation, "Success"
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Your piece of code is basically what I have and some times it won't work (I removed all the error checking to make the post clearer). I end up having "Worksheet not found" for files that actually have that worksheet, but not always. The main difference is that you are using a "For Each" statement and I am looping with the sheet index because I need that index too.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is the matter of case sensitivity when you could try this: `If StrComp(ws.CodeName, wsCodeName, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then`. BTW, why exactly do you need the (work)sheet index? Maybe you could upload one of the files that doesn't behave and post a link to it.

Comment: As you wrote a fully functional Sub (thanks for your time, only a `End With` needed changing), I tested it and it failed for a large file. I then run it with the debugger (same file) and added a stop in the line  `If ws.CodeName = wsCodeName Then`. This time it worked!?. From then on, the Sub always work with that file. So the problem is not with vba, there is something else.

Comment: About the index, I was using `Libro.Worksheets(index)` to refer to the worksheet later, but I like your way better.

Comment: So my point is to find a workaround because I doubt I'll find the root cause

Answer (score 0):

I'm somewhat of a VBA noob but I wrote this simple code a while back to search for a worksheet and delete it:

```
Dim sht As Worksheet

For Each sht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If Application.Proper(sht.Name) = Application.Proper("Company Data") Then
        Sheets("Company Data").Select
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.Delete
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    End If
Next sht
```

Maybe this can help?